# Allow moderators to filter community actioned posts in our flag queue

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools

Imagine if you will the following scenario:

- A low quality post (question or answer) was posted
- Community members flagged the post, and cast close or delete votes
- Post was closed or deleted

Because the post was flagged, it still shows up in our queue. This is a good thing, as we do need to have a look. We could have a serial spammer on our hands, or need to contact someone privately and nudge them in a better direction. We could also realize that we're  dealing with a Twitter crazed pile on and endeavour to calm someone that simply tried to ask a question. Moderation is seldom boring, but I digress.

What I'd like to be able to do is segregate viewing of this type of post in the moderator queue, similar to how we can sort flagged posts to only see things flagged as spam (or other criteria).

This would help us quickly see what was solved without our intervention, and decide if additional action on our part is warranted.

If implemented, this would also make the number of such posts more interesting. It could allow moderators to see what percentage of flags per year / quarter / month / day were handled *exclusively* by members of the community that don't have diamond moderator privileges. Such an indicator could help us refactor meta FAQ questions, create community bulletins or other things that help garbage collection overall.

Comment: I'd even expand this to questions or answers that were flagged after the community closed and / or deleted them. There are some people who simply do searches on already closed questions and flag all of them as "low quality" in an attempt to game the flag badges. It's pretty easy to dismiss these if they are all grouped together, which this kind of sorting might allow.

Comment: @BradLarson If implemented, I believe this would group those as well. In order to work, it would show any post in a closed or deleted state with unresolved flags still attached, regardless of when they were attached. The behavior you're describing does not always indicate gaming, however. Folks in the PHP tag maintain a backlog of really smelly closed questions so that they gain enough delete votes, and sometimes flag them for our help if they aren't getting enough velocity.